# Suspension height on Grand Cherokee 2011 v8 5.7L without air suspension

Tags: suspension, chrysler, grand-cherokee

I have a Jeep Grand Cherokee Overland 2011 v8 5.7L.

I recently convert the suspension to conventional (remove quadra-lift) due to too many problems and cost. Chrysler did it.

Aside from the warning that always appears when vehicule start, the front suspension is a lot lower than what is was with air suspension.

They installed coil-spring 68029621AF (ZNG, ZAG).

Lights were fine before and now they can't illuminate the car in front of me. I know I can just lift them. But it appears to me that there is a major problem,

Questions:

- I wonder if this is the right part number for my car (according to the web, it appears to me to be a good one)?
- What is the meaning of ZNG ZAG and all others 3 letters types?
- What is the proper height and how to measure it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!